# Connection between MongoDB Atlas and AWS giving timeout error?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm new to AWS so I apologize for any newbie stuff.

I'm trying to connect a MongoDB Atlas M0 cluster with our AWS EC2 instance, which is running a nodejs / react stack. The problem is that I can't make these two instances connect - AWS and MongoDB that is. When trying to use the backend sign in function (our nodejs api), it just gives this error:

```
Operation `user_profile.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
```

This is our index / connection:

```
import config from './config';
import app from './app';
import { connect } from 'mongoose'; // MongoDB
import { ServerApiVersion } from 'mongodb';

import https from 'https';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

const makeLogger = (bucket: string) => {
    const s3 = new AWS.S3({
        accessKeyId: <ACCESS_KEY_ID>,
        secretAccessKey: <SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>
    });
    return (logData: any, filename: string) => {
        s3.upload({
            Bucket: bucket, // pass your bucket name
            Key: filename, // file will be saved as testBucket/contacts.csv
            Body: JSON.stringify(logData, null, 2)
        }, function (s3Err: any, data: any) {
            if (s3Err) throw s3Err
            console.log(`File uploaded successfully at ${data.Location}`)
        });
        console.log(`log (${filename}): ${logData}`);
    };
};
const log = makeLogger('xxx-xxxx');
log(config.MONGO_DB_ADDRESS, 'mongo_db_address.txt');

const credentials = <CREDENTIALS>

connect(config.MONGO_DB_ADDRESS, {
    sslKey: credentials,
    sslCert: credentials,
    serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1
}) //, { useNewUrlParser: true })
.then(() => console.log('Connected to MongoDB'))
.catch((err) => console.error('Failed connection to MongoDB', err));

app.on('error', error => {
    console.error('app error: ' + error);
});

app.listen(config.WEB_PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${config.WEB_PORT}`);
});
```

One of the endpoints giving the timeout error:

```
 router.post('/signin', async (req, res) => {

        var form_validation = signin_schema.validate({
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password,
        });

        if (form_validation.error) {
            console.log('form validation sent');
            //return res.status(400).send(form_validation);
            return res.status(400).send({
                kind: 'ERROR',
                message: 'Sorry - something didn\'t go well. Please try again.'
            });
        }

        var User = model('model', UserSchema, 'user_profile');

        User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, (err: any, the_user: any) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).send({
                    kind: 'ERROR',
                    message: err.message
                });
            }

            if (!the_user) {
                return res.status(400).send({
                    kind: 'ERROR',
                    message: 'the_user undefined',
                });
            }

            compare(req.body.password, the_user.password)
                .then((result) => {

                    if (result == true) {

                        const user_payload = { name: the_user.name, email: the_user.email };
                        const access_token = sign(user_payload, config.SECRET_TOKEN);

                        res.cookie('authorization', access_token, {
                            httpOnly: true,
                            secure: false,
                            maxAge: 3600000,
                        });

                        return res.send({ kind: "LOADING" });
                        // return res.send(access_token);

                    } else {

                        return res.status(400).send({
                            kind: 'ERROR',
                            message: 'Sorry - wrong password or email used.'
                        });

                    }

                })

        })
    });
```

The strange thing is that I can connect from my local developer machine, when running our frontend. Just as I can connect from wsl2 ubuntu cli.

On the Mongo side, I have whitelisted every possible ip address. On the AWS side, I have created the outbound security group policy required. Regarding the inbound, I think it is correct. I've allowed access on the ports 27000 - 28018.

Again - I'm new to AWS, so if anyone can tell me what it is I'm simply not understanding here, I would be very grateful

Thanks

Comment: Are you using mongoose? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yes I am - currently importing from mongoose.

Comment: Is it not possible to use mongoose ?

Comment: I think there is a problem with how you are connecting.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions as to what this could be ? I've been working on it for days now, and I simply cant figure it out.

Comment: Edit your question and include your code. Read the link in my first comment.

Comment: Include your code that generates the error. My guess is that you have code that follows connect instead of being inside `then()`. The method `connect()` returns a promise. You must wait for the promise to resolve before executing other code. That completion happens within `then()`. Otherwise, you should use `await`.

Comment: The code generating the error is in another file. One containing various api endpoints like signup, signin, signout etc. It's all of these that throw a timeout error. I included the rest of the index.

Comment: I do not have a crystal ball to see your code. Read this guide and update your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm failing to see how it can be the connection ? I mentioned above that I can connect and use the DB from my local machine when running the frontend / backend locally and connecting with MongoDB Atlas. Just as I can use the mongo shell. It is only when our AWS instance tries to connect with MongoDB Atlas.

Comment: Because you have a timing problem. The connection has not completed before you are accessing the connection. The fact that it works on your local system does **NOT** matter in this situation.

Comment: And this is true even though our Mongo cluster is external ? We are not running the mongo cluster locally - thats external.

Comment: So my colleague corrected the error. Apparently the connection string, which is contained in .env, should NOT have any quotation marks & there should be a DB name before the parameters in the url. The url supplied by MongoDB Atlas doesn't have this.
In other words, it was not a timing problem. The code is fine.

Comment: No, your code is not fine. It did not detect that error as I mentioned in my comments. If you had proper error handling and code paths, a proper error message would have been returned.

Answer (score -1):

open mongodb atlas Network Access
open 0.0.0.0/0  (includes your current IP address)